# Unable to find class file in MVC structure - Beginner

Tags: grails, groovy

I have created a Grails project using the GGTS (the IDE). I also created a `DOMAIN` class named it `Person` and placed it inside the Package structure `project.app.domain`.

I also created a `Controller` class called `PersonController` and placed it inside the package structure `project.app.controller`

Code as follow:

**DOMAIN**

**// NOTE: resides inside the package structure `project.app.domain`**

```
 class Person {

        static constraints = {
            firstName(blank:false, maxSize:70)

        }

        int id;
        String firstName;
        String lastName;
    }
```

**CONTROLLER**

**// NOTE: resides inside the package structure `project.app.controller`**

```
class PersonController { 

    def scaffold = Person

    def index() {
        render "Hello World"
    } 
}
```

I don't think the `Domain` `Person` is not found when i say `scaffold = Person` when i say about. Is this is the mistake i am making. If so how can i fix it?

Error message that i got:

```
| Error 2014-02-16 12:53:22,754 [FileSystemWatcher: files=#261 cl=java.net.URLClassLoader@2501e081] ERROR plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager  - Plugin [controllers:2.2.4] could not reload changes to file [/Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/workspace-ggts-3.4.0.RELEASE/project/grails-app/controllers/project/app/controller/PersonController.groovy]: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Message: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   Line | Method
->> 695 | run in java.lang.Thread
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->> 695 | run in java.lang.Thread
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: project.app.controller.PersonController.propertyMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: propertyMissing(java.lang.String)
->> 695 | run in java.lang.Thread
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
```

AFTER CLEANING

```
| Error 2014-02-16 13:29:41,651 [Thread-15] ERROR plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin  - Error configuration scaffolding: null
Message: null
   Line | Method
->> 695 | run in java.lang.Thread
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: project.app.controller.PersonController.propertyMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: propertyMissing(java.lang.String)
->> 695 | run in java.lang.Thread
```

Comment: You've got `import project.app.domain.Person` in your controller yeah?

Comment: @Xeon `/grails-app/domain & /grails-app/controllers` are packages created within the IDE. When i make both package name the same then it works. But Why can't i include different package names as i have done?

Comment: Can you post the full sources including `package` and `imports` statements?

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try running the grails clean command and try starting the grails app again?

```
grails clean
```

Comment: Still no luck. After cleaning i get some other error message. I have added it to my post above.

Comment: Can you try replacing the scaffold code (**def scaffold = Person**) with this 
**static scaffold = true**

Comment: You could also try restarting your IDE

Comment: I tried both. Nothing worked. I think its with the `package` structure i created. `project.app.domain` and `project.app.controller`. Help?